# Add values to null object property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next object:

```
obj: {
   id: 1,
   status: 0,
   data: null
}
```

when I am adding new value to data:
obj.data.someVal = 1;
I'm getting 2 error, one from lint:

> ESLint: Assignment to property of function parameter
> 'data'.(no-param-reassign)

Other one during run:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'someVal' of null

Comment: `obj.data.someVal` looks like data should be an object.. you can do `obj.data = {someVal :1 }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the object with a variable:

```js
let obj = {
   id: 1,
   status: 0,
   data: null
};

obj.data = {};
obj.data.someVal = 1;

console.log(obj)
```